# VMware convert to Virtualbox?

Tags: vmware, virtualbox, virtualization

I downloaded a Kali Linux ISO VMware image thinking that it would be able to run in Virtualbox as well.  However, this only seems to be the case with .vmdk files, and my image is a .vm.tar.gz file.  Virtualbox does not recognize it as a valid ISO file, and I am not sure how to convert it. The entire thing is

```
kali-linux-1.0-i386-gnome-vm.tar.gz
```

The goal is to be able to run this in a Virtualbox, is there any way to convert this from VMware to Virtualbox?

Comment: you might want to check out Packer; not sure if it could do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [VirtualBox does support the VMDK container format used by VMWare](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails), but the file you have is *not* a VMDK file, but is probably a compressed virtual machine file. Unpack the file using an archive  manager that supports .tar.gz such as 7-zip ([some instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/215629/how-to-open-a-tar-gz-file-in-windows)) and then add that using `Machine→Add` (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>) from VirtualBox.

Comment: I am using Windows Vista, so the closest thing to an archive manager I can think of is 7-Zip, and that doesn't do anything for me...

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf According to the answers in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/215629/how-to-open-a-tar-gz-file-in-windows), it is possible to extract the file using 7-Zip.

Comment: Ok, you were right; I was able to extract it to the point of being a vm file, but now what? When I go to file -> import I am able to see the kali...vm folder, but upon opening the folder, it is empty. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf It's probably empty because none the files in the folder are supported by VirtualBox. Please list the files in the folder; I'm suspecting it could be an ISO-like folder.

Comment: When I select file and import, I can navigate to the extracted kali folder, if I attempt to open the folder, it's empty, but if I explore it, it shows: kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm, kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm.nvram, kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm.vmsd, kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm.vmx, kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm.vmxf, and kali-linux-i386-gnome-vm-s001 through 016

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf I think it's my mistake; you should use Machine→Add (Ctrl+A).

Comment: Same results. The file is not in .vmdk format, so I suppose it is incompatible with Virtualbox.  Thanks though; I guess I'll just download the normal 64-bit kali linux.

Comment: It _does_ seem to be a VMWare virtual machine according to [this](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html); but the virtual hard disk file is missing. You can install Kali Linux in VirtualBox from the standard .iso file.